# If $f$ is Holomorphic and non zero then so is $f'/f$ on some region $R$

Tags: complex-analysis

In my notes I am told to take this as true without proof, which is cool... for some.

$f^{-1}$ is holomorphic by a property of holomorphic functions.

To show that $f'/f $ is Holomorphic, I think I would have to show that the limit

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(x+h)f(x)-f'(x)f(x+h)}{hf(x)f(x+h)}$$

If I have multiplied it out correctly, exists. $\forall x \in R \subset \mathbb{C}$

Am I along the correct path?

Comment: You might do this. Buut you might also already know that the product of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic, and that the composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic, and that $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=f'(z)\cdot(f(z))^{-1}$ is holomorphic.

Comment: How do you know that $f'$ is holomorphic ??

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Isn't a holomorphic function infinitly differentiable? In fact, it's equal to its own (absolutely) convergent power series. Wouldn't the derivative of an absolutely convergent power series again be an absolutely convergent power series? I put question marks because I'm not sure.

Comment: I am unsure. If that is the case then I have no issue. but yes to the convergent power series part

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640/why-are-differentiable-complex-functions-infinitely-differentiable

Comment: The title is wrong because it claims $f'/f$ is holomorphic *and* non-zero